# Most efficient method of creating a local notification system with Firebase

Tags: android, notifications, firebase

I created a chat app using Firebase. I opted to use locally built notifications to notify users of messages.

Currently inside the onChildAdded() method (in the FirebaseArray class I forked)  the system works like this:

```
if (isUserInChatScreen == false) {
      //build notification         
}
```

The system works fine (prior to android severing the connection), but, because the user's account must listen to the changes of several different chat nodes I believe this is not a scalable implementation as the amount of listeners required is potentially equal to the amount of contacts the user has - which could potentially be hundreds.

I solved this by making the path of the chat like this: `specificUser/chats/specificChatID/`. Each user writes on the other user's corresponding specificChatID location, so, for every open chat there are 2 nodes. One where userA writes their messages to userB's specificChatID node, and one where userB  writes their messages to userA's specificChatID node.

Because of Firebase's bandwidth and storage limitations it makes sense for each user's specificChatID node to only store the other user's messages, therefore, the messages of a single conversation are split between userA's and userB's respective specificChatID nodes.

**The problem is:** for each user to see both sets of messages, the sender's messages have to be stored locally to avoid having two listeners per chat. I think it's preferable to store the messages inside a snapshot so I can merge it with the other incoming messages and take advantage of Fireabase's offline storage capability. Is it possible to write to a Snapshot offline? Is there a better way to have locally built notifications that would accommodate a large amount of contacts per user?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of describing your problem please create an [MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include the things you have already tried.

Comment: I understand the principles of MVC, the reason I chose not to post as much code as what you want is because I have solved the problem as I already said 'The system works fine', I am asking for a different approach 'Is there a better way to have locally built notification', or, if it is possible to  to write to a Snapshot offline. And the problem with the approach I took in making notifications for multiple users is hard to exemplify non-textually because the problem is a question of efficiency, but the code itself runs as expected

Comment: I suppose you can't have more than one chat on screen or? If you suppose that only one chat is visible at any time, you could implement a global listener in your `Application` class - one that listens for changes for the current user. Then when the data changes, you'd have to check what data has changed - if it's the chat you have visible right now or one in the background. If it's one in the background, fetch this chat and then notify the user. You could call it lazy-loading.

Comment: I think what you outlined is the best approach. But the trouble is, if both users have to have copies of the chats in their own Firebase nodes, I would be writing twice as much data to Firebase which would cost twice as much. Whereas, if both users only have a copy of what the other user has said (thus saving bandwidth and storage) I need to find a way of merging the incoming messages, with the outgoing messages which are stored locally. What would you suggest the best way is to merge the messages?